# A hint to show that $S^n$ is infinite

Tags: real-analysis

I have an exercise to prove that $S^n \subset \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ is infinite. Now, I've tried proving by contradiction, supposing that $S^n$ is finite and finding a contradiction, but I couldn't go much further. Another try was to show that stereographic projection is bijection with one infinite set, but I think that this is too much for a simple exercise.

Can someone give just a small hint on how to start this?

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: A hint may be that $S^n$ contains $S^1$.

Comment: As you mention, the stereographic projection yields a bijection from a subset of $S^n$ to an $n$-dimensional Euclidean space, which is infinite (assuming $n\neq 0$).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could argue that $S^1$ is infinite, then note that there is a bijection between $\{x \in S^n \mid x_1 = \dots = x_{n-1} = 0\}$, a subset of $S^n$, and $S^1$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

For any $\theta\in[0,2\pi)$, we have

$$\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta+0^2+\ldots+0^2=1$$